# Typo3 Unsupported validation option(s) found

Tags: validation, properties, typo3, fluid, extbase

Im working on an example from a typo3 extension book, and I‘m at the part to create own validators.
In my Controller I placed the following:

```
/**
* Title of the blog
*
* @var string
* @validate NotEmpty, \Lobacher\Simpleblog\Validation\Validator\WordValidator(max=3)
*/
protected $title = '';
```

In the file simpleblog\Validation\Validator\WordValidator.php is this code:

```
<?php
namespace Lobacher\Simpleblog\Validation\Validator;

class WordValidator extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\AbstractValidator {
    public function isValid($property) {
        $max = $this->options['max'];

        if (str_word_count($property, 0) <= $max)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->addError('Verringern Sie die Anzahl der Worte - es sind maximal '. $max .' erlaubt!', 1383400016);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But if i try to edit an entry typo3 says: Unsupported validation option(s) found: max

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a protected member `$supportedOptions` that defines the allowed parameters of your validator.

This member has to be an associative array, with the option names as keys, and the option configuration as values. The option configurations are numerically indexed arrays, where the array entries have the following meanings:

- Index 0: default value for the option (mixed)
- Index 1: description of the option (string)
- Index 2: type of the option (string, values are "string", "integer" etc.)
- Index 3: whether the option is required (boolean, optional).

An example from the [NumberRangeValidator](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/_number_range_validator_8php_source.html#l00041), not using the fourth option:

```
protected $supportedOptions = array(
    'minimum' => array(0, 'The minimum value to accept', 'integer'),
    'maximum' => array(PHP_INT_MAX, 'The maximum value to accept', 'integer'),
    'startRange' => array(0, 'The minimum value to accept', 'integer'),
    'endRange' => array(PHP_INT_MAX, 'The maximum value to accept', 'integer')
);
```

Comment: Yes, this works, thank you. But if I try to edit an entry which contains more then three words, typo3 throws me an exeption: "An error occurred while trying to call Lobacher\Simpleblog\Controller\BlogController->updateFormAction()." If I try to create a new entry, everything works fine.

Comment: That exception is usually thrown if a validation error occurs when fetching a stored object from the database. I have not found a solution to really debug it. What I do if this happens is to remove all validations on class members one-by-one and see when the problem goes away. Maybe you can speed that up by just checking validations that might go wrong.

Comment: I figured out the solution. I add "@ignorevalidation $blog" to the updateForm action and now everything works fine.

Comment: But that disables validation of the blog... not a good idea. Or is the `updateAction` the action that shows the form to edit the blog?

Comment: I got two actions, updateFormAction and updateAction. updateFormAction shows the form and updateAction updates the entry in the repository.

Comment: In that case you should get to the bottom of the problem, and not just deactivate validation that fails. You could produce a vulnerability by doing that.

Comment: As far as I understand, typo3 validates the object before it loads the view. If the validation fails, it cannot load the view and this generates a loop.

Comment: TYPO3 does validation at multiple times:

1. When the user has edited an object and submitted the form. It is expected that this validation might fail (if the user entered invalid data). Then the edit-form should be shown again, along with error messages. To be able to show the edit-form again, the edit-action (updateFormAction in your case) must be able to get an invalid object for prefilling, so you add a @dontvalidate annotation or something similar.

Comment: 2. When an object is loaded from the database. If this validation goes wrong, you have invalid data in the database. This is a bug, and the data was potentially inserted by an attacker. In this case, the error you showed above is shown, as a string where the output of the view should be.

Comment: Yes, currently I have "@dontvalidate" at my updateFormAction.

Comment: Oh, ok... I did misread your comment above. Sorry for the buzz.